# Append properties in Maven shading plugin

Tags: maven, jar, maven-shade-plugin

I'd like to migrate my project from Gradle to Maven.
I need a fat jar from my project, and I have multiple dependencies and each of them contain a properties file in the same location.

In the Gradle shadow plugin I could do the following:

```
transform(com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.PropertiesFileTransformer) {
    paths = ['META-INF/org/languagetool/language-module.properties']
    mergeStrategy = 'append'
}
```

In Maven with the shade plugin I tried the following from official docs (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#PropertiesTransformer):

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.properties.PropertiesTransformer">
    <resource>META-INF/org/languagetool/language-module.properties</resource>
    <ordinalKey>ordinal</ordinalKey>
    <alreadyMergedKey>already_merged</alreadyMergedKey>
    <defaultOrdinal>0</defaultOrdinal>
    <reverseOrder>false</reverseOrder>
</transformer>
```

But unfortunately it doesn't merge all of the files, just uses one :(
Do I use the wrong transformer or are the parameters wrong? I could find any documentation about the parameter values.

Comment: I have the same problem and just looked through the debug log of Maven. It looked to me like the `PropertiesTransformer` only merges the dependencies files. I just tested this and the result was positive: the files of the project are not observed. Moreover, the highest manually configured `configuration.ordinal` value remains! Thats no solution (havent found one yet) but at least we know the problem now.